# Long Text in TikZ Mindmap Nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps, shapepar

When using TikZ mindmap library on long texts, the text just get's a thin line while the node scales up (compare below).
When using the `text width` argument, the inscribed rectangle gets wider but still, the bubble is way to big for the inscribed text.

How can I properly use the space of a mindmap node?

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap, trees}

% laymans blindtext
\newcounter{int}
\newcommand{\blindtext}[1]{\setcounter{int}{0}\loop This is a long text. \addtocounter{int}{1}\ifnum\value{int}<#1\repeat}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mindmap,
    concept color=gray!50,
    text=black,
    level 1 concept/.append style={
        level distance=9 cm,
        sibling angle=72}
    ]
    \node[concept] {} [clockwise from=0]
        child {node[concept] {\blindtext{10}}}
        child {node[concept, text width=4.5cm] {\blindtext{10}}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: question]

Answer (score 3):

One can use the [`shapepar`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/shapepar/shapepar.pdf) package to cast the text into a round shape.

Why doing so directly fails with "Runaway argument?" is above me but one can draw an empty node first and overlay the text afterwards:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz, shapepar}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap, trees}

% laymans blindtext
\newcounter{int}
\newcommand{\blindtext}[1]{\setcounter{int}{0}\loop This is a long text. \addtocounter{int}{1}\ifnum\value{int}<#1\repeat}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mindmap,
    text centered,
    concept color=gray!50,
    text=black,
    level 1 concept/.append style={
        level distance=9 cm,
        sibling angle=72}
    ]
    \node[concept] {} [clockwise from=0]
        child {node[concept, text width=4.5cm] (node1) {}};

    \node[extra concept, fill=none, draw=none, text width=4.5cm] at (node1) {\Shapepar{\circleshape} \blindtext{10}\par};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: answer]