# Argument of \pgfmath@dimen@@ has an extra }

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, mindmaps

Using `TikZ` and `pgf` versions `v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)`, I tried to compile the following code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,mindmap}
\tikzset{grow cyclic list/.code={%
  \def\tikzgrowthpositions{{#1}}%
  \foreach \n [count=\i,remember=\i]in {#1}{}%
  \let\tikzgrowthpositionscount=\i%
  \tikzset{growth function=\tikzgrowcycliclist}}}
\def\tikzgrowcycliclist{%
  \pgftransformshift{%
    \pgfpointpolar{\tikzgrowthpositions[mod(\the\tikznumberofcurrentchild-1,\tikzgrowthpositionscount)]}%
      {\the\tikzleveldistance}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[small mindmap, concept color=blue!20,  
  every child node/.style={concept}]
\node [concept] (languages) 
  {O} [grow cyclic list={90,0,-45,210}] 
    child { node {A} }
    child { node {B} }
    child { node {C} 
      [clockwise from=0, sibling angle=45]
      child { node {C1} }
      child { node {C1} }
      child { node {C1} }
    }
    child { node {D} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which is a part of the Mark Wibrow's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281226/tikz-getting-angles-in-mindmaps-right). But it throws the following error:

> Argument of \pgfmath@dimen@@ has an extra }. ^^Ichild { node {D} };

Does anybody know how to resolve it?

Comment: Looks like there was a bug in TikZ previously that makes `remember` variables persist outside the loop, which is fixed in newer TikZ version.

Comment: Somewhat related question, [tikz pgf - How to get the number of elements in a \foreach loop? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147544/how-to-get-the-number-of-elements-in-a-foreach-loop) which mentions that previously the variable would persist. (now it doesn't)

Comment: @user202729: But the latest version is the one I have tested with (v3.1.9a), right?

Comment: What I mean is the answer abuse foreach bug... well egreg's answer covered it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the old answer exploited a misfeature of `\foreach` that has been since fixed.

What happened was that the “count” that was “remembered” was still available at the end of `\foreach`, but this is wrong: you'd clobber the meaning of `\i` in your case. And if you had an accented “î” in some node…

There's a much easier way to count elements of a list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,mindmap}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \clistcount \clist_count:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\tikzset{
  grow cyclic list/.code={%
    \def\tikzgrowthpositions{{#1}}%
%    \foreach \n [count=\i,remember=\i]in {#1}{\global\let\tikzgrowthpositionscount=\i}%
    \edef\tikzgrowthpositionscount{\clistcount{#1}}%
    \tikzset{growth function=\tikzgrowcycliclist}
  }
}

\def\tikzgrowcycliclist{%
  \pgftransformshift{%
    \pgfpointpolar{%
      \tikzgrowthpositions[mod(\the\tikznumberofcurrentchild-1,\tikzgrowthpositionscount)]%
    }%
    {\the\tikzleveldistance}
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  small mindmap,
  concept color=blue!20,  
  every child node/.style={concept}
]
\node [concept] (languages) 
  {O} [grow cyclic list={90,0,-45,210}] 
    child { node {A} }
    child { node {B} }
    child { node {C} 
      [clockwise from=0, sibling angle=45]
      child { node {C1} }
      child { node {C1} }
      child { node {C1} }
    }
    child { node {D} };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I left commented the alternative `\foreach` method, but my suggestion is much more efficient.

For a “pure Ti*k*Z” solution

```
\tikzset{
  grow cyclic list/.code={%
    \def\tikzgrowthpositions{{#1}}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\tikzgrowthpositionscount{dim({#1})}%
    \tikzset{growth function=\tikzgrowcycliclist}
  }
}
```

Comment: `dim`! I always learn something new about PGF/Ti*k*Z!

Comment: @JasperHabicht This has a story. I once found it in the code, but not in the manual, so I opened an issue in the Github site. It turned out I was assaulted by a well known person. I'll not mention the futile reasons, except that the function wasn't documented because it was buggy when the list contained a single item. But as a consequence of the issue report, the bug was fixed and the function found its place in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that `\tikzgrowthpositionscount` needs to be set inside the `\foreach` loop and it should be made global to be accessible outside the loop. The `remember` option only stores the last item value, but it does not make the variable accessible outside the for loop (might have been changed at some point in time).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,mindmap,calc}
\tikzset{grow cyclic list/.code={%
  \def\tikzgrowthpositions{{#1}}%
  \foreach \n [count=\i]in {#1}{%
    \global\let\tikzgrowthpositionscount=\i%
  }%
  \tikzset{growth function=\tikzgrowcycliclist}}}
\def\tikzgrowcycliclist{%
  \pgftransformshift{%
    \pgfpointpolar{\tikzgrowthpositions[mod(\the\tikznumberofcurrentchild-1,\tikzgrowthpositionscount)]}%
      {\the\tikzleveldistance}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[small mindmap, concept color=blue!20,  
  every child node/.style={concept}]
\node [concept] (languages) 
  {O} [grow cyclic list={90,0,-45,210}] 
    child { node {A} }
    child { node {B} }
    child { node {C} 
      [clockwise from=0, sibling angle=45]
      child { node {C1} }
      child { node {C1} }
      child { node {C1} }
    }
    child { node {D} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]